# Vue + Monaco including local path along with cdn URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, monaco-editor

When trying to include monaco into my project, this is the error it throws:

`Monaco initialization error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop\project\https:\cdn.jsdelivr.net\npm\monaco-editor@0.33.0\min\vs\editor\editor.main.js'`

Why would it try to include a local directory along with a cdn url?